# How to Add a Real-Time Vertical Line to Shared X-Axis Plot in Plotly Python?

Tags: python, datetime, plot, time, plotly

I'm using Plotly to create two time series plots, and I want to add a vertical dashed red line at the current time to both plots while sharing the same x-axis. However, when I use the 'fig.add_vline' function, it seems to place the line in the distant past. How can I make it show the current time instead? Below is a modified version of my code with two plots sharing the x-axis and some sample data to work with:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Sample data
data1 = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-09-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'Value1': [10, 12, 15, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 10, 12]
}

data2 = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-09-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'Value2': [5, 7, 9, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 7, 6]
}

# Create subplots with shared x-axis
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)

# Add a scatter plot to the first subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data1['Date'], y=data1['Value1'], mode='lines', name='Value1'), row=1, col=1)

# Add a scatter plot to the second subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data2['Date'], y=data2['Value2'], mode='lines', name='Value2'), row=2, col=1)

# Get the current time as a numeric timestamp
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().timestamp()

# Add a vertical dashed red line at the current time to both subplots
fig.add_vline(x=current_time, line=dict(color='red', dash='dash'), annotation_text='Current Time', row='all')

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The situation that is happening is depicted on the leftmost side of the line chart, as the x-axis of the line chart is the datetime value and the current time value is the smallest float value. So the solution is to align the x-axis values. Rather than drawing a line graph with float values and later editing it to a string scale for the time series, you can simply change to the vertical period setting and draw a graph with the current time value as a string.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import pandas as pd
import datetime

# Sample data
data1 = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-09-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'Value1': [10, 12, 15, 8, 9, 11, 13, 14, 10, 12]
}

data2 = {
    'Date': pd.date_range(start='2023-09-01', periods=10, freq='D'),
    'Value2': [5, 7, 9, 6, 8, 10, 11, 12, 7, 6]
}

# Create subplots with shared x-axis
fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.1)

# Add a scatter plot to the first subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data1['Date'], y=data1['Value1'], mode='lines', name='Value1'), row=1, col=1)

# Add a scatter plot to the second subplot
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=data2['Date'], y=data2['Value2'], mode='lines', name='Value2'), row=2, col=1)

# Get the current time as a numeric timestamp
current_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime(format='%Y-%m-%d')

# Add a vertical dashed red line at the current time to both subplots
fig.add_vrect(x0=current_time, x1=current_time, line=dict(color='red', dash='dash'), annotation_text='Current Time', row='all')

# Show the plot
fig.show()
```

[image]